# How to remove date in Date Picker(Xamarin Forms)

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a **Date Picker** in Xamarin Form Page. in date picker today's date set by default. Is there any option to remove that date so i can send a null value when user don't select the date from **Date Picker**.

Comment: I think you can do it by just setting its value to `null`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis that's not possible because with the default `DatePicker`, `DateTime` can't have a null value. You could either add a checkbox (e. g. "Enable Date"). If the checkbox is not selected, work with null. If it's selected, work with whatever value your `DatePicker` contains... Or you can write your own `DatePicker`: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20028/datepicker-possible-to-bind-to-nullable-date-value

Comment: Use DateTime.MinValue instead of null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to write the CustomRederer for DatePicker

**In PCL:**

```
 using System;
 using Xamarin.Forms;
 namespace IncAlert
   {
    public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
      {
        public CustomDatePicker()
         {
        TextColor = Color.FromHex("#282828");
         }
      public static readonly BindableProperty EnterTextProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "EnterText", returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(CustomDatePicker), defaultValue: default(string));
    public string EnterText { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomFontFamilyProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "CustomFontFamily", returnType: typeof(string), declaringType: typeof(CustomDatePicker), defaultValue: default(string));
    public string CustomFontFamily { get; set; }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CustomFontSizeProperty = BindableProperty.Create(propertyName: "CustomFontSize", returnType: typeof(float), declaringType: typeof(CustomDatePicker), defaultValue: default(float));
    public float CustomFontSize { get; set; }

   }
}
```

**Xamarin.Android:**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.Res;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Text;
using Android.Util;
using IncAlert;
using IncAlert.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
using Graphicss = Android.Graphics;

  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomDatePicker), 
  typeof(CustomDatePickerRender))]
  namespace IncAlert.Droid
  {
   public class CustomDatePickerRender : DatePickerRenderer
    {
    public CustomDatePickerRender(){}

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        try
        {
            CustomDatePicker element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
            }
            else
            {
                element = e.OldElement as CustomDatePicker;
            }

            if (Control != null)
            {
                //var element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                //gd.SetCornerRadius(45); // increase or decrease to changes the corner look
                gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                //gd.SetStroke(2, global::Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
                this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.EnterText))
                {
                    Control.Text = element.EnterText;
                }
                Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf
   (global::Android.Graphics.Color.Black));//for placeholder
                if (element.CustomFontSize != 0.0)
                {
                    Control.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, element.CustomFontSize);
                    //Control.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, element.CustomFontSize);
                }

                if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir65")
                {
                    Graphicss.Typeface font = Graphicss.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "AvenirLTStd-Medium.ttf");
                    Control.Typeface = font;
                }
                else if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir45")
                {
                    Graphicss.Typeface font = Graphicss.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "AvenirLTStd-Book.ttf");
                    Control.Typeface = font;
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
        //this.Control.InputType = InputTypes.TextVariationPassword;
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        try
        {
            CustomDatePicker element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
            if (Control != null)
            {
                //var element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
                GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
                //gd.SetCornerRadius(45); // increase or decrease to changes the corner look
                gd.SetColor(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                //gd.SetStroke(2, global::Android.Graphics.Color.Gray);
                this.Control.SetBackgroundDrawable(gd);
                this.Control.SetRawInputType(InputTypes.TextFlagNoSuggestions);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(element.EnterText))
                {
                    //Control.Text = element.EnterText;
                }
                Control.SetHintTextColor(ColorStateList.ValueOf(global::Android.Graphics.Color.Black));//for placeholder
                if (element.CustomFontSize != 0.0)
                {
                    Control.SetTextSize(ComplexUnitType.Dip, element.CustomFontSize);
                    //Control.SetTextSize(Android.Util.ComplexUnitType.Dip, element.CustomFontSize);
                }

                if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir65")
                {
                    Graphicss.Typeface font = Graphicss.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "AvenirLTStd-Medium.ttf");
                    Control.Typeface = font;
                }
                else if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir45")
                {
                    Graphicss.Typeface font = Graphicss.Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Forms.Context.Assets, "AvenirLTStd-Book.ttf");
                    Control.Typeface = font;
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
        //this.Control.InputType = InputTypes.TextVariationPassword;
       }
   }
}
```

**Xamarin.iOS:**

```
  using System;
  using IncAlert;
  using IncAlert.iOS;
  using UIKit;
  using Xamarin.Forms;
  using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomDatePicker), 
  typeof(CustomDatePickerRender))]
   namespace IncAlert.iOS
    {
     public class CustomDatePickerRender : DatePickerRenderer
       {
    public CustomDatePickerRender(){}

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        try
        {
            CustomDatePicker element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
            }
            else
            {
                element = e.OldElement as CustomDatePicker;
            }

            if (Control != null)
            {
                //var element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
                var textGiven = element.EnterText;
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                Control.ExclusiveTouch = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textGiven))
                {
                    Control.Text = textGiven;
                }
                Control.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
                if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir65")
                {
                    Control.Font = UIFont.FromName("AvenirLTStd-Medium.ttf", 15f);
                }
                else if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir45")
                {
                    Control.Font = UIFont.FromName("AvenirLTStd-Book.ttf", 15f);
                }
                else
                {
                }
                if (element.CustomFontSize != 0)
                {
                    UIFont font = Control.Font.WithSize(element.CustomFontSize);
                    Control.Font = font;
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        try
        {
            CustomDatePicker element = Element as CustomDatePicker;

            if (Control != null)
            {
                //var element = Element as CustomDatePicker;
                var textGiven = element.EnterText;
                Control.BorderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None;
                Control.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
                Control.Layer.CornerRadius = 10;
                Control.ExclusiveTouch = true;
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textGiven))
                {
                    //Control.Text = textGiven;
                }
                Control.TextColor = UIColor.Black;
                if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir65")
                {
                    Control.Font = UIFont.FromName("AvenirLTStd-Medium.ttf", 15f);
                }
                else if (element.CustomFontFamily == "Avenir45")
                {
                    Control.Font = UIFont.FromName("AvenirLTStd-Book.ttf", 15f);
                }
                else
                {
                }
                if (element.CustomFontSize != 0)
                {
                    UIFont font = 
    Control.Font.WithSize(element.CustomFontSize);
                    Control.Font = font;
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }
       }
   }
 }
```

**In XAML:**

```
   <local:CustomDatePicker EnterText=" "/>
```

(OR)

**In C#:**

```
     CustomDatePicker regDateEntry = new CustomDatePicker()
        {
            EnterText = " ",
            CustomFontSize =15,
            CustomFontFamily = "Avenir45"
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using two different Styles defined in App.xaml. One style is default DatePicker style and another is for disabled date picker. The disabled style sets the TextColor same as the BackgroundColor of the control.

I also have a checkbox to enable/disable whether user want's to set a date or not (depending upon your application needs). On checking the checkbox, I am setting default Style and on unchecking, I am setting disabled Style.

Here is the result:

Checked:

[image: DatePicker Enabled]

Unchecked (this also has date, but not shown to user):

[image: DatePicker Disabled]